# Tag children needs synonyms

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I think we need to create a few synonyms for the [children](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children):

- kids
- infrant(s)
- toddlers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synonym mapping for 'infant' already existed, I added the others. *Tags* don't need to be created before one is legitimately used (unused tags get cleaned up anyway) but I feel *synonyms* are essential to help new users tag posts correctly. (For instance, someone posting about children could think the word 'kids' and not have a suggestion pop-up because it hasn't been set as a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we need to create synonyms until they have been actually used by someone. Pre-emptively increasing the number of tags doesn't sound like good idea to me -- we have a ridiculous amount of tags already, and there's no need to increase it unnecessary.

Comment: Personally I don't mind either way. I thought we aleady had a synonym or two for this one though.